# How can I hide Navigation Bar without hiding the status bar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to hide the Bottom navigation bar only and not the status bar. Most of the code I am getting is hiding both the navigation bar and the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below function. Owing to changes in `Android R`, `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, `setSystemUiVisibility` etc are being deprecated. I have made the function to handle this scenario.

```
public void hideBottomNavigationBar() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
         getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
         WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();
         if(controller != null) {
           controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
           controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
         }
      } else {
         getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

      }
}
```

Another thing to note about using `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION):

> There is a limitation: because navigation controls are so important, the least user interaction will cause them to reappear immediately. When this happens, both this flag and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN will be cleared automatically, so that both elements reappear at the same time.

Inorder to work around this limitation you can set `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` as well like this:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

But this only works SDK 19 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
View v = getWindow().getDecorView();  
int options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION  
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;  
v.setSystemUiVisibility(options);
```